# debounce method inside redux thunk

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I have action with async method inside and I want to debounce it

```
export const onSearchChange = query => dispach => {
    if (query === "") {
        dispach({ type: SOME_TYPE, payload: query })
    } else {
        dispach({ type: SOME_TYPE, payload: query })
        searchProductsCall(query).then(payload => {
            dispach({ type: SOME_OTHER_TYPE, payload })
        })
    }
}
```

how can I debounce `searchProductsCall` using `lodash` or something else ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create the debounced function first and call that function instead of your `searchProductsCall`.

The following code should make sure the first dispatch is called right away in all cases (it probably changes the UI?) and that it calls the `searchProductsCall` only after the debounce and when there is a non-empty query.

```
export const debouncedSearchProductsCall = _.debounce((query, dispatch) => {
    if (query !== "") {
        searchProductsCall(query).then(payload => {
            dispatch({ type: SOME_OTHER_TYPE, payload })
        });
    }
}, 200);

export const onSearchChange = query => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: SOME_TYPE, payload: query });
    debouncedSearchProductsCall(query, dispatch);
}
```